# Nodemon restart at every change, not at the saves

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, nodemon

I'm creating a nodejs project and I've been used nodemon since the beginning. It used to go very well, the server was running while I was coding and at the time I saved the file, nodemon restarted the server. Now, every time I change a little bit one of the files, without saving, nodemon restart the server.
I use VS Code and this problem started when I did some changes in settings (but not in nodemon ones). One of them was to connect my folder with a git repository. Could it be that *vs code source control* get every single changes and nodemon see that? Is there any setting comand I can use to force him to work only at explicit saves?

(I hope my EN wasn't so bad)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you accidentally turned on autosave and VSCode saves your work after every small change, to turn it off, go to fo to

*File => Preferences => Settings*

find AutoSave and turn it of

Comment: It was setted on "After Delay", and it didn't restart only after that delays, so there's something strange but setting it to off resolved the problem so thanks!

Comment: This was driving me insane. Thank you, didn't think it might be the IDE!